# Deleting RLMObjects related to a "primary" RLMObject

Tags: ios, database, realm

Hi Guys I am using Realm DB with iOS and my situation is, I have one central RLMObject in my data base which has many RLMObject connected to him. The behaviour I want to achieve is when I delete my "central" RLMObject I want the other ones to be also deleted, because I don't need the data they store. 
Thanks for Your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm-Cocoa doesn't yet have support for cascading deletes, even though it is being worked on. This is being tracked by the following issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1186.

As a workaround, you can manually iterate over the relevant objects and delete them.

Comment: This is what I supposed... It can be really a problem (lot of work), to get rid of "garbage" data from the realm in case one have a complicated DBModel. It is good that You are working on that.